# NetPipeActivator service stops handling calls

Tags: wcf, iis, workflow-foundation, was

I have a bunch of WCF/WF services hosted on IIS 7.5 that call each other through named pipe bindings.

The binding configuration is the same on client and server:

```
<bindings>
    <netNamedPipeBinding>
          <binding transactionFlow="true" transferMode="Streamed" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions" name="NetPipeBinding">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
           </binding>
     </netNamedPipeBinding>
</bindings>
```

Up to that, everything works perfectly, but suddenly the services won't receive calls and the active WF service instances will become suspended. At this point in time, the resume command won't start them because "There is no endpoint listening on net.pipe://localhost..."

After a restart of the NetPipeActivator service, everything will come up again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is an issue in SMSvcHost.exe that is fixed with this hotfix:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2504602/en-us